# Como instanciar HttpClient no typescript Angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript

Baseado neste exemplo para o Http, gostaria de saber como instanciar o HttpClient:

```
 **constructor() {  
    const browserXhr: BrowserXhr = new BrowserXhr();  
    const baseResponseOptions: ResponseOptions = new ResponseOptions();  
    const xsrfStrategy: CookieXSRFStrategy = new CookieXSRFStrategy();  
    const backend: XHRBackend = new XHRBackend(browserXhr, baseResponseOptions, xsrfStrategy);  
    const requestOptions: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions();  
    const http: Http = new Http(backend, requestOptions);  
this._http = http;**
```

Então gostaria de saber como instanciar o HttpClient desta mesma forma.

obs: a forma `**constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}**` não me serve neste caso pois preciso instanciar dentro de uma classe *typescript* e desta forma ou estendendo outra classe e fica exigindo o *http* como parâmetro.

Umas considerações atuais a mais...

Eu preciso criar uma classe que quando instanciada eu informe a nome da tabela que ela vai trabalhar mas não quero ter a necessidade de informar mais parâmetros no construtor da classe como tenho que fazer atualmente conforme este exemplo abaixo (assim é como funciona atualmente):

```js
@Injectable() 
export class MvsDbTable implements OnInit {
constructor( 
    @Inject('_tableName') public _tableName: string, 
    @Inject('_HTTP') public _HTTP: HttpClient  ) {}
```

Então eu instancio a classe em um serviço:

```js
    public _tblFinances = new MvsDbTable('Finances', this._Http);
```

Mas eu gostaria de não ter que informar este parâmetro ", this.http".

Então eu gostaria que fosse assim:

```js
@Injectable() 
export class MvsDbTable implements OnInit {
constructor( 
    @Inject('_tableName') public _tableName: string ) {
    this._HTTP = new HttpClient(this._Handler);   }
```

Só que não funciona instanciar o parâmetro _Handler pois é abstrato então não pode ser instanciado.

Então eu instanciaria a classe em um serviço assim:

```js
    public _tblFinances = new MvsDbTable('Finances');
```

Fica apenas mais limpo o código, da primeira forma já funciona. O que eu tento descobrir é como instanciar o HttpClient dentro da classe sem ter que passar o HttpClient como parâmetro no constructor como eu fazia com o Http que também funcionava.

Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Dentro do app.module.ts você pode definir como o provider será instanciado.

Crie um objeto informando a classe que será fornecida (provide), o método que fará o new (useFactory) e as dependências necessárias para criar sua classe (deps):

```
import { FactoryProvider } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    <FactoryProvider>{
      provide: HttpClient, HttpClient ou sua classe que herda HttpClient
      useFactory: requestLoader,
      deps: [ HttpHandler ]
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

export function requestLoader(handler: HttpHandler) {
  return new HttpClient(handler); // HttpClient ou sua classe que herda HttpClient
}
```

Dessa forma você pode usar o construtor pedindo o service HttpClient ou sua classe que herda HttpClient

**Importante:** Se o seu objetivo for interceptar os requests para inserir tokens de autorização, por exemplo, essa não é mais a melhor forma de fazer a partir do angular 4.3.4.
Para isso deve-se utilizar os *interceptors* (Exemplo baseado no artigo [building-http-interceptor-angular-5](https://theinfogrid.com/tech/developers/angular/building-http-interceptor-angular-5/)):

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MyHttpInterceptor } from './myhttp.interceptor';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
],
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
],
providers: [
    {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: MyHttpInterceptor,
    multi: true
    }
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

myhttp.interceptor.ts:

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class MyHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor() { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        // logar para teste
        console.log('intercepted request ... ');

        // Clonar a requisição para adicionar o cabeçalho
        const authReq = req.clone(
            {
                headers: req.headers.set('headerName', 'headerValue')
            }
        );

        console.log('Sending request with new header now ...');

        // enviar a requisição modificada para a proxima classe da cadeia
        return next.handle(authReq)
            .catch((error, caught) => {
                // interceptar a resposta de erro e logar
                console.log('Error Occurred');
                console.log(error);
                // returnar o erro para o metodo que chamou
                return Observable.throw(error);
            }) as any;
    }
}
```

Comment: Marcelo, desculpe pela minha demora mas havia deixado o projeto um pouco de lado e só retomei agora, infelizmente não havia visto sua resposta, agradeço muito pela sua ajuda.

Comment: Não funcionou e me parece que há no seu código uma mistura entre http e httpclient (a não ser que eu esteja enganado).
Mas mesmo adaptando para httpclient apenas, não funcionou, o httpclient para ser instanciado pede um parâmetro handler, coloco-o e a chamada .GET não é executada. Não dá erro nem nada, apenas gera exceção de erro mas sem nem fazer a requisição rest.

Então eu continuo precisando da informação de como instanciar um HttpClient sem ter que injetar no constructor.

obrigado!

Comment: @MarceloVareladaSilva desculpe a demora para resposta. Realmente havia um problema no código de exemplo. Fiz a correção e adicionei mais alguns detalhes. Por gentileza, verifique se responde a sua dúvida.

Comment: Mais uma vez obrigado por responder. Fiz uma modificação na minha pergunta tentando esclarecer mais minha necessidade, pode revisar acima.

Comment: Acredito que nesta sua resposta a parte do requestLoader seja o caminho do que eu necessito mas infelizmente não tive o conhecimento de como implementar a sua sugestão no meu serviço, no módulo eu implementei direitinho como sugeriu mas não consegui usar no serviço, como neste exemplo abaixo que não funciona:

@Injectable() 
export class MvsDbTbl {
constructor( @Inject('_tblName') public _tblName: string ) {
    this._HTTP = requestLoader();  
 }

Basicamente o que eu preciso é instanciar o HttpClient dentro de uma classe sem fazer uso de Injeção de Dependencia.
Obrigado

Comment: E se você criasse um service com um método generate no qual ele recebe a referência do httpclient pelo construtor e quando você chama o método generate ela dá um new na classe MvsTable, injetando o http? O service seria uma espécie de builder para abstrair a necessidade de criar o http client na mão (inclusive receberia o http Singleton do próprio angular)

Comment: @MarceloVareladaSilva @Injectable() export class MvsTableBuilderService { constructor(private http: HttpClient) { } ‎generate(tableName: string) { ‎ return new MvsDbTable(tableName, this.http); ‎} }

Comment: Desculpe a demora, estive bem ocupado entregando um projeto. Sim, assim funciona, outro dia pensei nisto mas como tinha outra prioridade não havia tentado, agora para não te deixar sem resposta acabei de testar e funciona mesmo, não queria ficar dando voltas mas depois da migração do http (que dava para instanciar) para o httpclient vai ter que ser assim mesmo. Ficou muito bom, muito obrigado pela sugestão. Abraço!